why i am not receiving the google gemini response in formated paragraphs in html page
I Am using a google gemini api in my django, everything is going fine, response generated my gemini in terminal is perfect with space between two paragraph and all, but when i am passing this response to html page, all the formatting is gone, there is no line of space between two paragraph, and i dont nkow why it is producing unnecessary stars ** in the response, please tell me how i fix it.
this is the image of response generated in terminal.

this is how it is looking in html page.
I Am storing the response generated by gemini in database, and then fetching it on html page.
Please help me and tell how i make it look more tidy in html, also tell me how i ignore those unnessary stars.
this is what my models.py looks like

this is the html template
{% load static %}
<!-- main/templates/home.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
'home.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to our website</h1>

    {% for data_1 in data_test %}
    <div>
        <h1 style="color: antiquewhite;">{{data_1.Question}}</h1>
        <br>
        <p style="color: aqua;">{{data_1.Answer}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>

</html>


It seems to produce markdown.

Can you share the template that generates the HTML page?

Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. [edit] the question and include code fragments with the code sample button ({}).

i have added a html template

can you please clarify what should i do?

The text is generated likely in Markdown which aims to be a lean formatting language with minimal overhead. For example, items between double asterisks (i.e. **foo**) are written in boldface.
You can generate HTML from markdown effectively with a library, like:
pip install markdown
an then use properties to wrap these to html:
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from markdown import markdown


class Data_1(models.Model):
    Question = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    Answer = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True)

    @property
    def question_html(self):
        return mark_safe(markdown(self.Question))

    @property
    def answer_html(self):
        return mark_safe(markdown(self.Answer))
and render with:
{% for data_1 in data_test %}
  <div>
    <p style="color: antiquewhite;">{{ data1.question_html }}</p>
    <br>
    <p style="color: aqua;">{{ data1.answer_html }}</p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}


Note: Models in Django are written in PascalCase, not snake_case,
so you might want to rename the model from Data_1 to Data1.



Note: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in snake_case, not PascalCase, so it should be: question instead of Question.

